# The language is changed when I upload it to the ASP.NET MVC server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have a problem, when I upload the project to the server, the language of the validation messages is changed.

When I test it locally I have it in Spanish and when I upload it to the server it is changed to English.

Because it could be.

In the config I have it clear that it has to be Spanish.

```
<globalization uiCulture="es" culture="es-AR" />
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the language pack for .NET at same version of your web project.

For .NET 4.6, see: https://www.microsoft.com/es-ES/download/details.aspx?id=48135

For .NET 4.6.1 https://www.microsoft.com/es-ES/download/details.aspx?id=49977

After install, restart the server.